# What is the purpose of the middle wire on the ribbon?

Tags: button

I am new to circuits and am trying to repair a device. What is the purpose of the middle button on the ribbon? It is the one that circles around 4 of the buttons on the device top. I am trying to replace the button panel with a breadboard and buttons - what would the wiring for this be like?

[image: 3rd wire on ribbon is connected to 4 buttons]

Comment: Well, a button must short something to something, right? It is a common, ground likely

Comment: You literally just posted a schematic of the circuit (the traces being visible in your photo). This shows the "wiring."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just follow the connections:

[image: Button Wiring]

"Green" is common, in that it goes to each switch.  Pressing any button connects "green" to another color.

Comment: Also, blue is a screen-printed insulator that allows the conductors to cross. A seemingly unnecessary gimmick, since this layout could have been done on a single layer without crossing - but perhaps the pinout on the board this connects to was already frozen, so they had no easy way around this.

Answer (score 2):

I see four switches and five conductors on the flex cable.  The "middle wire" is almost certainly common and pressing a button connects its specific wire to the common one.  A multimeter will be able to show you which is which.